# How can I change the color of the not filled in circle in the mat-spinner

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using a mat spinner like this:

```
<mat-progress-spinner class="mat-spinner" [color]="'primary'" [mode]="'determinate'"
    [strokeWidth]="2" [diameter]="16" [value]="10">
</mat-progress-spinner>
```

The circle will be filled in for only 10%. I want to give a light color blue style to the other 90% thats not filled in. How can I styles that part of the spinner?

I tried:

```
.mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
    stroke: #6aa1fe;
}
```

But that only styles the 10%.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `box-shadow` to create a filled shadow circle for `mat-progress-spinner` like this:

```
mat-progress-spinner {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #6aa1fe inset;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

where `10px` is `strokeWidth` of your spinner. This is [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/filled-mat-progress-spinner).

Please take note that, accroding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13517809),

> This works in modern browsers only. For example: No IE 8 support.
> [See caniuse.com (box-shadow feature)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) for more info.

---

**See more:**

- Some other solutions (like using `outset`): [Placing border inside of div and not on its edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601357/placing-border-inside-of-div-and-not-on-its-edge).
- [Using border-radius and box-shadow together (CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714765/using-border-radius-and-box-shadow-together-css)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would recommend that you create a custom directive for the mat-progress-spinner element.

Here's how I solved your problem using custom directives:

1. Create a new directive in Angular by running the following command:

```bash
    ng g d spinner-variable-color
```

2. I updated the directive so it looked like this (you can refactor/simplify the code but I just did this fast to see if it works):

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[spinnerVariableColor]'
})
export class SpinnerVariableColorDirective {

  constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef
  ){}

  ngAfterViewInit(){
      const element = this.elem.nativeElement;
      const progress = element.getAttribute('aria-valuenow');
      const circle = element.querySelector('circle');

      if (progress > 20) {
        circle.style.stroke = '#6aa1fe';
      } else {
        circle.style.stroke = 'black';
      }
  }
}
```

3. You can now use it in your component like this:

```html
<mat-progress-spinner spinnerVariableColor [value]="progress"></mat-progress-spinner>
```

where **progress** is just a variable I created to keep track of progress.

Hope this helped you solve your problem :)
If you want to know more about custom directives in Angular I have a great article about it on my website -> [What Is Custom Directives In Angular](https://learnjavascripts.com/development/web-development/frameworks/angular/what-is-custom-directive-in-angular)